# JavaScript does not show methods and properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I am installing and configuring Visual Studio Code to work with JS.

In the main index file.js everything works correctly and the hints display methods and properties.
An event is triggered here and we run the execute method to execute the command.
We pass an argument with a certain type to the command.
The file index.js:

```
client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {
    await command.execute(interaction);
}
```

But in the command, this type is not recognized and shows the type any. Properties and methods are not displayed. I do not know how to cast types in JavaScript.
Is there any way to display properties and methods automatically? Maybe there are extensions?
The file command.js:

```
async execute(interaction) {
    // parameter interaction: any
    await interaction.reply(`Reply`);
}
```

I have successfully configured jsconfig.js, so that the program hints work for js.
The file jsconfig.js:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "target": "ES6"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: How _is_ it supposed to know what type you expect `interaction` to be? Use TypeScript, or at least JSDoc comments, to provide that metadata.

Comment: Or just turn off Typescript for your user/workspace preferences. Add a `.jsonfig.json` file to your root folder with `{"compilerOptions": {"checkJs": false}}` perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like that

```js
/**
 * @param {Date} myDate The date
 * @param {string} myString The string
 */
function myFunction(myDate, myString)
{
    //do stuff
}
```